# Flash Builder 4 - External CSS theme caching issues

Tags: css, flex4, flash-builder

I have a Flash Builder 4 application which uses custom themes by loading external style sheets at run time. The user can change the themes via a dropdown menu. Everything works correctly except for some weird caching issues. As you change themes, the main background color will change but certain elements will remain cached.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: please describe the way you are updating application with new style.also tell us which exactly components are going to be redrawn? maybe you might call invalidateDisplayList after each update or something similar.